# NestJS param decorator return type

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Is there any way to infer the return type of a param decorator in a route handler method?

The `UserName` decorator is returning a `string`, but the route argument is `any`.

[image]

Comment: Can you show how `@UserName()` returns a string? I don't believe this type of type inferring is possible, but I'd like to take a look

Comment: Sorry @JayMcDoniel, the code in the screenshot had a syntax error. I've updated the attachment.

The `@UserName()` decorator returns the literal string "Random User". However in the route handler the argument is typed as `any`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe Typescript has this functionality. I'd be interested to see if anyone has a solution though

Comment: There's no way to do that. But you could do something like this: define a type alias like `export type UserName = 'Random User'` and use it `@UserName() user: UserName`